# Filling in the parameters of an Audio resampling method

Tags: android, android-ndk, audio-recording, resampling

I am trying to do resampling in android using this library https://github.com/intervigilium/libresample/blob/master/src/net/sourceforge/resample/Resample.java#L6
but I dont know exactly what to fill in the Parameters

I want to Resample an audio file

```
File mySound = new File("/mySound.wav");
```

to `44,100 kHz`
how do i do it with this library: Library  Code shown below..

```
package net.sourceforge.resample;

public class Resample {

public static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
public static final int MAX_CHANNELS = 2;
public static final int CHANNEL_MONO = 0;
public static final int CHANNEL_LEFT = 0;
public static final int CHANNEL_RIGHT = 1;

private static final String RESAMPLE_LIB = "resample";

static {
    System.loadLibrary(RESAMPLE_LIB);
}

public static native void downmix(short outputBuffer[], short inputLeft[], short inputRight[], int numSamples);

public static native int resample(double factor, short inputBuffer[], short outputBuffer[], int numSamples);

public static native void initialize(int inputRate, int outputRate, int bufferSize, int channels);

public static native double getFactor();

public static native int process(short inputBuffer[], short outputBuffer[], int channel, boolean isLast);

public static native void close();
}
```

Comment: Have you read the library's documentation?

Comment: maybe you should ask on their github?

Comment: there is no documentation for the port im trying to work with. I'll go ahead and ask on the github page